# Exposed filter : search term with select which 'field' to search by

Tags: views

I have a view which displays a list of nodes with exposed filters. Everything works perfectly.

I would like to add a filter like this:

- one input text
- one drop-down.

The list items represent fields of content type.

The user can write a search term in the input text and select which 'field' to search by. i.e. All, Title, Summary, ...

Is that possible? How I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom module inspired by your question. You can find it [here](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/shabirahmad/2642802)

It is not created/approved as a full project on Drupal.org. But it will approved soon. Download the module, enable it. Under filter add a filter that says `Exposed fields Filter` then select the fields you want to expose to visitors. Only those field will appear to visitors which you select here.

I hope it helps you for now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your module but I have an error when I add the exposed fields filter in my view. http://i.stack.imgur.com/mh33O.png   http://i.stack.imgur.com/WKjyl.png Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I have updated the link to the code on drupal.org. It has some fixes. hope that helps